# regex to replace string inside shell script

Tags: regex, shell, sh

I have a string in a line which I want to replace. The test that I need to replace is in the line below

```
<property name="name"><![CDATA[string to replace]]></property>
```

I was trying to use regex and form groups. I can form three groups but not able to replace them within my shell script using sed or egrep. I am trying to replace it with another string such as 'dummytext'

```
(.*CDATA\[)([a-zA-Z0-9].*)(]]><.*)

sed 's/(.*CDATA\[)([a-zA-Z0-9].*)(]]><.*)/\1dummytext\3/'
```

I have most of my script written in bash, so don't want to switch to python or another language. The find and replace can be dome using another tool if not sed.

Comment: Could you post in the line which you want to perform the operation on....

Comment: @acesmndr the line is `<property name="name"><![CDATA[string to replace]]></property>`

Comment: Use -E flag like: `sed -E 's/(.*CDATA\[)([a-zA-Z0-9].*)(]]><.*)/\1dummytext\3/'`

Comment: @oguzismail I tried the '-E' flag and it works well on the terminal but not inside a script. trying some other flags nows

Comment: `sed 's/\[.*\]\]/[dummytext]]/' file` If it is a multi-line file with many `[...]]` involved, then locate and anchor the `<property name="name">` to identify the exact line, e.g. `sed '/^<property\ name="name">/s/\[.*\]\]/[dummytext]]/' file`

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidC.Rankin that solved it for me.

Comment: Good, glad it helped. It takes a while to make friends with Regex, `sed` and `awk`, but all are necessary evils in working seriously with any type text.